# Why is domain name being appended to simple string in To: field of email message (SMTP)

Tags: email, smtp, protocols

I am testing an SMTP mail server and I wanted to know what happens if I put just plain text as the To: text, rather than a valid email address. In other words, the test message looked like this:

```
mail from:<example@abc.com>
rcpt to:<myselfr@mydomain.com>
data
To: some-text
From: more-text
Subject: Test email #1
Email to test non address in To/From fields
.
```

The resulting email had the From and To fields like this:

```
To: some-text@mydomain.com
From: more-text@mydomain.com
```

It appeared that the either mail client or SMTP server was appending the recipient's domain to the plain text in the To/From fields.

I had thought that everything in the data part of the message (inside the "envelope" was just whatever the sender wanted to put there. Why/How is it getting modified, and is that modification by the sending server, receiving server or the mail client?

I also tried sending an email with no To/From information at all and in the mail client To: was blank and From: had the `rcpt to:` information.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on assumption that domain-less email address referrers to "this mail server".

MTA/SMTP server "fixes" the addresses to make them valid on other servers e.g. after forwarding.